# Defining a column with different types in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, types, calculated-columns

I have a `Data Frame` (df) from excel (`pd.read_excel()`) and I need to define a new column with different types such as:

```
df['new col'] = df['Date1']
df.loc[condition('Date1'), 'new col'] = 'string'
```

Where `df['Date1']` is a column of Dates and `condition('Date1')` checks if 'Date1' is in a given range of value while `string` is a fixed text. My code is giving error. How can I define my new column?

On condition() function let:

```
a = df4['Date2'] - pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')
b = df4['Date2'] + pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')

condition('Date1')= df['Date1'].between(a, b, inclusive=False)
```

Comment: How I can check?

Comment: It return dtype: bool.

Comment: my function check if date1 is in a given range:

Comment: I have shared my function

Answer (score 0):

You need only simplify your code - from `df4['Date1'].between(a, b, inclusive=False)` is returned boolean Series, so need it only pass to `loc`:

```
a = df4['Date2'] - pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')
b = df4['Date2'] + pd.Timedelta(2, unit='d')

mask = df4['Date1'].between(a, b, inclusive=False)

df4['new col'] = df4['Date1']
df4.loc[mask, 'new col'] = 'string'
```

Better alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df4['new col'] = np.where(mask, 'string', df4['Date1'])
```

**Notice**:

Mixed values in same Series is possible, but then performance should be decrease and some functions should be broken, so be careful.

Comment: @stefanodv hmmm, so if run my code what is exactly error? Please share las line of error.